# Facebook login using java-facebook-api

Tags: java, javascript, database, jakarta-ee, facebook-graph-api

I am struggling from couple of days, to add facebook login to web app using java facebook api, since my web application is java/j2ee application. I went through few blogs, since facebook doesnt have provide the official java library.

I went through this blog and code and tried to make a prototype, but its not working, i could say i spent lot of time debugging the code and removing the errors which I got instead of testing the code.

1. [Logging in with Facebook Java API](http://straylink.wordpress.com/2008/06/03/logging-in-with-facebook-java-api/)
2. [Facebook Java api example to publish on Wall](http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/facebook-java-api-example-to-publish-on-wall/)

I also took a look at the facebook javascript login button which is quite simple and easy go, but I have couple of clarifications to be made her.

When the user logins I want to retrieve his email_id,profile_picture and also his name, rest of the things I will ask user to fill it up.

My questions are here

1. How do I retrieve the profile_picture of the user?
2. A user should be able to see the name and picture of the users who all are logged in 
   use facebook login,so should be save the picture in the database or I can get it dynamically?
3. How do I manage the database, suppose the user A visits my site and clicks on fb login for the first and the same user A visits my site for the site and clicks the fb login button, how should I managing the user sessions?

Kindly help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think the best you can try to do, and I offer my help to do it, is "convert" the php sdk classes (base-facebook.php and facebook.php) into java classes. After that it will be easy to answer your questions. By the way, if you gonna do some server-side processing, why not using php instead of java-ee?